# What are Coins For?

Tags: cardinal-quest

I've noticed that whenever I pick up a weapon in [Cardinal Quest](http://www.cardinalquest.com/), the game compares it to my current one and if one of them is better, the lower quality one is 'sold'.  When this happens, I get a coin.

[image: The Character Status bar contains a value for 'coins'.]

What can I do with these coins?  As far as I know, there's no in-game shop.  Can you actually use them for anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are 100% worthless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the developer (who couldn't figure out how to answer anonymously), the coins were part of a planned 'shops' feature that has since been turned into the sequel, *Cardinal Quest 2*.  So yes, they're entirely useless.